# Accuracy of sys.dm_exec_procedure stats

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to trend some system performance over time, but I've hit a couple of stumbling blocks with `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` that I can't reconcile.

If I take sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats and join it to sys.dm_exec_query_stats matching on plan_Handle, I am getting some data that doesn't make sense to me.

Execution_Count - Sometimes this matches very well between the two and other times it is off by tens of thousands of executions. Looking at procedure stats I have one procedure that has 771 executions.   It has 4 matching query plans, all of which show 1 execution_count.

Total_Worker_Time - Procedure_Stats is reporting 2x-3x what summing the query_plans do.  295,977 versus 130,212.

Last_Worker_Time - Procedure_Stats versus sum of query_stats matches almost exactly.

Min_Worker_Time - Procedure_Stats versus a min of query_stats is close

Max_Worker_Time - Procedure_Stats versus a sum of query_stats is close

Total_Elapsed_Time - Procedure_Stats versus a sum of query_stats is off.  Procedure_Stats is 7x longer

Last_Elapsed_Time - Procedure_Stats versus a sum of query_stats is very close

min_Elapsed_time - Procedure_Stats versus a min of query_stats is close.

Max_Elapsed_Time - Procedure_Stats versus a sum of query_stats is off.  Procedure_Status is 4x longer.

I find it odd that some of these match up and other do not, but the mismatches here make me distrust this data in general.   I'm most interested in the total times, the execution_counts (to get averages) and the min/max times.

Could anyone explain why these mismatch or which is best to use and how do I know I can trust it?  Does the max time and total time in procedure_stats include client wait times or something else that skews these?

Comment: Could they be CPU time? 1 query running on several CPUs takes up more CPUs than "real" time

Comment: Hi Phil, I'm honestly not sure what would skew them.... If so then which is correct to believe and why would the Last and Min match, but not the total?

Comment: A few things come to mind... On the close items this is because although the values are given in microseconds they are really only accurate to milliseconds. Secondly, anything that has OPTION(RECOMPILE) will obviously skew the results as the execution count will be 1 and the plan generation will increase. Look to see if you have mismatched plan generation numbers in the same SP. Third, SQL Server 2005+ has statement level recompiles and won't recompile the entire SP - again look at plan generation num. Additionally deferred compiles may also be hitting you.

Comment: Hi Sean, I was thinking of the statement level recompiles as well, but my expectation was that I would see varying dates in the sys.dm_exec_Query_Stats.   Right now those times are a few milliseconds behind the cached time shown in sys.dm_exec_Procedure_Stats, which makes sense.  The procedure generates a plan and then the individual statement level plans are created underneath of that.   On a statement level recompile I would have a datetime on there drastically different (more than 1s) off from the procedure cache time?